# mkdir(): Invalid argument

Tags: php, xampp, mkdir, invalid-argument

I'm trying to create a folder using `mkdir()` in a PHP script.
In the location of `file.php` I have a folder named "details". In that folder I want to create another folder.

I use this code:

```
mkdir("details/$id", 0777, true);
```

But I always get this warning:

> **Warning**: mkdir(): Invalid argument in **C:\Users\Lenovo\xampp\htdocs\public_html\file.php** on line **40**

I checked that `$id` isn't empty by echoing it.

How to create the folder with `$id` name under details folder?

Comment: What is the value of $id?

Comment: first try this `mkdir("details/$id");`

Comment: @SahilGulati It still shows the same warning

Comment: @klutt The value of $id is int

Comment: Make sure your folder details exists and also that your `$id` is not null

Comment: Try: `mkdir("details/".trim($id), 0777, true);`

Comment: @SahilGulat I already said I check it is not null, and the folder is exist on the public_html folder

Comment: @IdoNaveh are you using IIS?

Comment: @LucaJung No. I'm using XAMPP

Comment: @LucaJung This is solution was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use your $id inside the string, you have to concatenate it

```
mkdir("details/". $id, 0777, true);
OR
mkdir("details/{$id}", 0777, true);
```